# Are there any way to stop typing 'go' in sqlcmd?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlcmd

If I remember correctly, last time `Microsoft Sqlcmd` require each command to end with ';' and hit Enter key to execute the command.

However, currently, we need to type the `GO` each time to execute the command.

So, are there other alternative such that when we hit Enter key after ending the command with ';', it will Execute the command?

Comment: Hitting Enter after `;` is `mysql` interactive query tool.

Comment: @RemusRusanu: actually nearly all query tools do it that way (Oracle, Postgres, Firebird, HSQLDB, ...).

Comment: (Just a guess.) The semicolon is a *statement* delimiter in T-SQL. Previously it was completely optional because it was impossible to write an ambiguously interpreted *batch* (aka *multi-statement query*) that had no statement delimiters. Based on that, the semicolon was probably chosen as a *batch* delimiter in `sqlcmd`. However, since SQL Server 2005, new features have begun to appear in T-SQL that enable you to write an ambiguous batch if you don't delimit the statements. So, to avoid the ambiguity interpreting the function of `;`, the need for a distinct batch delimiter must have arisen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you need to type a batch separator. The default is `GO`. However, you can change that by using the `-c` switch.

For example:

`C:\>sqlcmd -SServername -cFOO`

`1> select @@version`

hit enter

`2> FOO`

hit enter

This will run.

Can't get rid of the intermediate enter for you. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

As for workaround, it's possible to run queries via `sqlcmd` command in shell, e.g.

```
sqlcmd -Q 'SELECT 1'
sqlcmd -Q 'SELECT 2'
```

without typing `GO` each time.

For the convenience, in order to not type credentials each time, use an alias, e.g.

```
alias sqlcmd="sqlcmd -S hostname -U user -P pass -d db"
```

---

Here is another version of the shell alias:

```
alias RUN="sqlcmd -S hostname -U user -P pass -d db -Q"
```

Then just run:

```
RUN 'SELECT 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

GO is the batch terminator.  Without it sqlcmd doesn't know to send the batch to the server for execution.